# Venv command doesn't work to isolate my environment

Tags: python, bash, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

When I use the `python3 -m venv env` command and activate it with `source env/bin/activate` it doesn't help to isolate my virtual environment, since using the `pip list` or `pip freeze` continues to show me the libraries that I have in my normal environment (I understand that when activating the virtual environment there should be no more than 2 libraries).

Comment: Which libraries are you seeing that you don't think you should be?

Comment: Sometimes you might get off by using `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip`.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the `pip` provided by your virtual environment, and not a globally installed version? `which pip` should report something like `env/bin/pip`.

Comment: @chepner When I use `which pip` it shows me "/usr/bin/pip", in the folder called "env/bin/" there is no pip.

Comment: There's your problem. `/usr/bin/pip` *isn't* reporting on your virtual environment.